# Change default directory in putty after login (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, ssh, putty, syntax

Currently have a bat file set up to auto log into putty (cd "C:\Program Files\PuTTY"
start PUTTY.exe -ssh "Sever IP" -l "User Name" -pw "Password") WORKS FINE!!

But when i use the following syntax to automatically change the route to a different one it dose nothing
(cd "C:\Program Files\PuTTY"
start PUTTY.exe -ssh "Sever IP" -l "User Name" -pw "Password" -t -m cmds.txt)

In the cmds text file is a simple CD C:\Subfolder\subfolder

Is there an easier way..??

I have tried connection/ssh remote cmd in the putty GUI but dosent work

Please help thanks